# Spring + JWS + Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, tomcat, java-web-start

Is it possible to bundle Tomcat with a Spring application with Java WebStart & how ?

Comment: If there is a firewall involved then it will not work

Comment: How would a firewall be involved ? everything runs locally.

Comment: It's possible to execute Tomcat in embedded mode. But why do you want to start your client (Java WS) with a web container embedded?

Comment: The question was about creating an html based web application that can be started with Java WebStart. I still don't know how to do it in Java, I know it's doable with non-JVM SDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) provides support for embedding, you would then declare the jar file in the jnlp, and invoke the jetty server from the main application, then you've got a web server on the client.

As stated above, you may still need to overcome some firewall and policy issues.

Comment: This is an answer but Tomcat is another solution, I've created another question in a more accurate way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687333/how-could-i-embed-a-html-css-js-view-in-a-webstart-application