# How could I embed a html/css/js view in a webstart application

Tags: java, http, java-web-start

I would like to use a html/css/js view in my webstart project without requesting *all permissions*.

I figured out that I could use the java HTTPServer to process the requests but I need a way to avoid using real sockets, so that the HTTPServer instantiation doesn't ask for some permission.

Do you know any projects that achieve that ? and if not, what should I do to get an HTTPServer completely working locally (without hitting boundaries...) ?

edit: maybe an HTTPServer is too much, I maybe only need a HttpHandler..

Comment: Why are you pushing this question in the abysses without comments ? This is the future of webdesktop love it or hate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with HTML 3.2, [`JEditorPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) can render it, as shown [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).